# Subjectivity in answers

Tags: discussion

Subjective questions are not allowed on SO, so can I assume the same about answers?

I'm in a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720143/are-find-and-where-firstordefault-equivalent/14721250#14721250) about this, and while the answer itself is correct there is also a piece of subjective advice. We've agreed that the advice is subjective, but the author seems to think that I'm exaggerating.

Should I avoid such a discussion in the future, or do I have a point here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I think you have a point here in that the OP should be more clear about his recommendation being a matter of preference (to achieve more readable code, in his opinion).

So instead of "you *should* do xyz",  it would be better style to say "while both methods are equal, it is better coding style to do xyz, because it enhances readability" or somesuch. You are not wrong in pointing that out.

Still, I guess if he won't change his mind despite your comments, there is no point in discussing the issue any further. You can either leave it alone (and trust that your comments express your point of view), downvote, and/or post an answer of your own.

It's not about subjectivity as such, though, IMO. As he says, code readability opinions are often subjective. It doesn't mean they're not allowed on Stack Overflow. The issue is that he states a stylistic opinion as it were a technical fact.

Comment: It is, to an extent, a technical fact. There's no reason to have more methods than are necessary.

Comment: @Asad I see your point (now that you explained the language-specific issues at play here)

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you have a point: one should be transparent about what is stylistic preference and what is absolutely mandatory. In this case however, going by reductio ad absurdum, I could add 5 extra LINQ non-ops before I get to the FirstOrDefault. That is *objectively* worse.

It's pretty obvious (objectively) that the answerer's approach only improves the code here readability-wise <sup><sup>see tangential rambling</sup></sup>. If he were pushing a particular style of brace positioning in C# I could see your point.

---

**Tangential rambling:**

It probably also improves the code performance wise, since the *entire* collection no longer needs be filtered against the lambda expression when it is non-empty. Giving the lambda expression to FirstOrDefault directly saves you time because it can exit as soon as it's found the first item that satisfies the condition. Take this with a grain of salt though, I haven't done any perf testing at all.

EDIT: Nevermind, the link you provided shows that both are functionally identical, because of lazy evaluation.

Comment: I don't agree that it's obvious. In LINQ to Objects there actually is a [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8663897/247702) between `Where(predicate).First()` and `First(predicate)`, so it could be possible that the LINQ to Entities provider had a similar difference. It shouldn't, but didn't know for sure, so I asked.

Comment: @Stijn The conclusion arrived at in that post is that there *isn't* a difference between First and Where -> First. If there was (i.e LINQ didn't use lazy evaluation), Where -> First would be slower.

Comment: I feel like I went too far in all this, regardless, thanks for the conclusion :)